# Custom health checks for AWS EC2 autoscaling - if "healthy" status is not received regularly, the instance is deemed unhealthy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

AWS EC2 auto-scaling can use custom health checks. A script can check the instance health and call `aws autoscaling set-instance-health` to update the instance status to `Unhealthy` if the check fails.

However what if the instance becomes so unhealthy (CPU 100% used or network connection lost), that it could not even update its status to `Unhealthy`?

Is there a way to implement the EC2 auto-scaling custom health check in a way that, if the instance fails to send in `healthy` status regularly, for example every 5 minutes, auto-scaling group would treat the instance as unhealthy?

Comment: An instance should not set its own health, for exactly that reason. Something _outside_ of the instance should check if the instance is healthy. Can you tell us more about why you were wanting to do a custom health check?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. We observed sometimes a remote file system may become unreachable inside an instance and wish auto scaling could replace the instance should it happens. Yes we can check from outside. But it seems checking from inside and requiring consistent "healthy" status reporting is simpler and cheaper to implement. For example it doesn't require an additional instance. A simple Cron job is all it requires.

Comment: The standard Health Check goes to a particular URL and is happy if it receives a `200` response. So, you could point the Health Check to a URL that your instance responds to with a simple web server (eg Python app) -- if the file system is happy, return a `200`. If not, return something else and Auto Scaling will mark it Unhealthy. Plus, if the instance fails, it will do the same. Alternatively... Would a simple reboot fix the file system problem? If so, replacing the instance wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Going to a particular URL sounds like an ELB health check not an auto scaling group health check. And the instance in particular is not behind an ELB. But thanks for the suggestion, that certainly makes sense if the instance uses ELB.